# Telerik grid hierarchy how make client template for nested grid

Tags: grid, hierarchy, client-templates

This is typical example from telerik, I try create template for nested grid but without success

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(110);
             })               
             .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(6)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))            
            )        
            .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
    )

    <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
                .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(110);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(200);
                })
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(10)
                    .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
                )
                .ToClientTemplate()
        )
    </script>
```

How create client template for nested grid? Because `columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).ClientTemplate("#=OrderID# - #=ShipName#")` not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use without hashtag in 
columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).ClientTemplate("OrderID - ShipName")

[Conditional client template in Razor hierarchical grid](http://www.telerik.com/forums/conditional-client-template-in-razor-hierarchical-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but for anyone who search for this answer too:
Escape the template expression, to be evaluated in the child/detail context

Ex:
`columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).ClientTemplate("\\#=OrderID\\# - \\#=ShipName\\#")`

[Hierarchy Demo MVC with client template on child](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy)